# How do I implement forms for user input to register and login in Django when I already have the views using JWT?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I´m learning how to work with JWT(pyJWT) in Django, in this case I´m trying to authenticate users with it, I followed a tutorial and using postman it worked, I use mysql and the passwords were hashed and the tokens were generated succesfully, now the only thing left is to create the forms so the user can input his credentials but I don´t know how to do proceed.

Views.py

```
class RegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found')

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password')

        payload = {
            'id': user.id,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)


        }

        token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')

        
        response = Response()

        response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
        response.data = {"jwt": token

        }

        return response
    

class UserView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')

        if not token:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unathenticated!')
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Uathenticated')
        
        user = User.objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)

        return Response(serializer.data)
    

class LogoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        response = Response()
        response.delete_cookie('jwt')
        response.data = {
            'message': 'Success'

        }
        return response
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can connect DRF with Django Template, create another app for Django Template like how you work in Django. Then you can fetch api using jquery.

Also can use the below method, but I don't recommended this method always try to use jquery.
https://github.com/sumasreeeduru/Textyfi

`Note`: Use DRF for backend, try to integrate frontend with React, NextJS or any other JS library is commonly used by everyone.

Answer (score -1):

follow these steps:

- Import your views in the urls.py file which you create in your app
- You can test it in the postman
- Fetch with your API and pass the token in the headers
- Test the authorization